# Modifying a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone please explain why do i get a three at the end of the list, the if statement checks if the element in `x` list is equal to the `val` defined

```
x = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]
val = 2
print (x)
val =2
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)-1 , 0 , -1 ):
        if x[i] == val and x[j] != val:
            x[i] , x[j] = x[j] , x[i]
print (x)
```

Comment: Just print x at the end of each iteration and see for yourself how the substitutions go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code :

```
x = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]
val = 2
print (x)
val =2
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)-1 , 0 , -1 ):
        if x[i] == val and x[j] != val:
            print("x[",i,"]=",x[i]," ; x[",j,"]=",x[j])
            x[i] , x[j] = x[j] , x[i]
            print(x)
print (x)
```

I got this output :

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
x[ 2 ]= 2  ; x[ 6 ]= 4
[0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2]
x[ 3 ]= 2  ; x[ 5 ]= 0
[0, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2]
x[ 5 ]= 2  ; x[ 4 ]= 3
[0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2]
x[ 6 ]= 2  ; x[ 5 ]= 3
[0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2]
x[ 7 ]= 2  ; x[ 6 ]= 3
[0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

note that range(len(x)-1,0,-1) will be interpreted like [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. When i=7 and j=6 (at the end of the loops) x[ i ]= 2  ; x[ j ]= 3 so 3 is appended to x[7].